# Limit of Variant of Geometric Sequence with Common Ratio any Real Number Between 0 and 1

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was wondering if the result that the limit of a geometric sequence with common ratio $r\in(0,1)$ is 0 held if successive terms were multiplied by any real number between $0$ and $1$. In a recursion this would be $a_{n+1} = r_n a_n$, where $a_1 =1$ and $r_n$ is any real number between $0$ and $1$. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Take $r_n = 1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$, i.e. $$
a_{n+1} = \left(1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right) a_{n}.
$$

You have $$
a_n = \prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{k^2}\right) = e^{\sum_{k=2}^n \ln\left(1-\frac{1}{k^2}\right)}.
$$ 
However, $\sum_{k=2}^n \ln\left(1-\frac{1}{k^2}\right)$ converges to 
$$
\ell = \sum_{k=2}^\infty \ln\left(1-\frac{1}{k^2}\right) \in (-\infty, 0)
$$
so that $a_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} e^\ell > 0$.

(One can even prove this limit $e^\ell$ is equal to $\frac{1}{2}$, rewriting $$
\sum_{k=2}^\infty \ln\left(1-\frac{1}{k^2}\right) = \sum_{k=2}^\infty \left(\ln\frac{k+1}{k} - \ln\frac{k}{k-1}\right) = -\ln 2
$$
as a telescopic series.)

Comment: Ok, thanks for insightful response.

Comment: @TomasSmith: for what it's worth, you can check that a necessary and sufficient condition for convergence to $0$ is that $\sum_{k=2}^\infty \ln r_k = -\infty$.